# I have a problem solving a system of 2 non-linear (exponential) equations with two variables. Could anybody please help?

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations, exponential-function, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I have a system of 2 non-linear equations with two variables:

1) $e^n - e^m = 1$

2) $-\ln(e^{-m} ( e^{nr} + e^{m})) + nr + \ln ( e ^{-m} (e ^{m} + 1 ))=n  $

, where $n$ and $m$ are the two variables and $r$ is a constant. Also $m≠n$ and $n>0$.

I am having trouble solving the system. Can anybody please help? Stuck for days now. Also how do we convert each equation in their respective linear form? PLEASE! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your second relationship can be written

$$\operatorname{ln} \frac{e^m+1}{e^{nr}+e^m}=n-nr$$

otherwise said, taking the exponential of both sides:

$$\frac{e^m+1}{e^{nr}+e^m}=e^{n(1-r)}$$

Setting $u=e^m, v=e^n$, your system can be transformed into

$$\begin{cases}v-u&=&1\\ \frac{u+1}{v^r+u}&=&v^{1-r}\end{cases}$$

As you can "extract" $u=v-1$ from the first relationship, and plug its expression into the second one, you are left with :

$$\dfrac{v}{v^r+v-1}=v^{1-r}$$

Simplifying it by $v \ne 0$ (it is an exponential), we get:

$$v=0$$

which is contradictory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Should it help with the solution that $m≠n$? Also n is positive. (Made the edit in the original question.)

Comment: No, in this proof, I haven't use the fact that $m=n$ or $m \ne n$. In any case, there are no solutions.

Comment: Okay. Thank you once again. Could you help me find $r$ in terms of $m$ and $n$ in this:

$(e^n - e^m)n = -\ln(e^{-m} ( e^{nr} + e^{m})) + nr + \ln ( e ^{-m} (e ^{m} + 1 ))$.

Comment: You mean that $1$ is replaced by $n$ in the first equation ?

Comment: Apologies. Made the edit.

Comment: This new equation looks untractable for getting a closed form solution.

Answer (score 3):

From the second equation, we have:
$$\ln(\frac {e^m+1}{e^m+e^{nr}})=n(1-r)$$
So, $$\frac {e^n}{e^{nr}}=\frac {e^m+1}{e^m+e^{nr}}$$
Cross multiplying, $$e^{m+n}+e^{n(r+1)}=e^{nr+m}+e^{nr}$$
So, $$e^{nr}(e^n-1)=e^{m}(e^{nr}-e^{n})$$
So, from the first relation, we get: $$e^{n}=0$$
This means that $e^m=-1$, which is impossible, so the equations have no real solutions.

Edit: The only other possibility is that $e^{-m}=0$, and $n=0$, which I did not count because that is not a real solution either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Should it help with the solution that $m \ne n$? Also n is positive.

Comment: No, as I proved, it is impossible for solutions to exist. Can you spot any error in my proof?

Comment: Okay. Thank you once again. Could you help me find $r$ in terms of $m$ and $n$ in this:

$(e^n - e^m)n = -\ln(e^{-m} ( e^{nr} + e^{m})) + nr + \ln ( e ^{-m} (e ^{m} + 1 ))$.

Comment: A detail: you can stop at $e^n=0$ which is impossible (an exponential is never $0$).

Comment: Apologies. Made the edit. And thanks for your previous comment.

Comment: @Jean Marie true, I should have stopped there. Just wanted to make it more obvious.

Comment: @Blue yes, from the first relation, I edited it.